# Flutter: Convert the cached (.file) file to mp4 file

Tags: flutter

I have a video file. I save to cache this video file. And I want to play this video in other page. But when I save this video to cache I dont play video. this video appear in cache like this.

```
/data/user/0/com.example.flutter_cache_manager/cache/libCachedImageData/fc65e4a0-0fb7-11eb-a1ed-53020f3249ad.file
```

I need to convert this video to .mp4 file.

```
Future addCacheFiles() async {
        try {
          Uint8List bytes;
          String myPath = realPath + '/WhatCarCanYouGetForAGrand.mp4';
          _readFileByte(myPath).then((bytesData) async {
            bytes = bytesData;
            var file = await DefaultCacheManager().putFile(realPath + "/WhatCarCanYouGetForAGrand.mp4", bytes);
            print(file.path.toString() + " " + "kayıt etti");
          });
        } catch (e) {
          print("hata");
          print(e);
        }
      }

Future<Uint8List> _readFileByte(String filePath) async {
    Uri myUri = Uri.parse(filePath);
    File audioFile = new File.fromUri(myUri);
    Uint8List bytes;
    await audioFile.readAsBytes().then((value) {
      bytes = Uint8List.fromList(value);
      print('reading of bytes is completed');
    }).catchError((onError) {
      print('Exception Error while reading audio from path:' +
          onError.toString());
    });
    return bytes;
  }
```

thanks. by the way this code is running. I just need to convert to mp4 file.

Answer (score 0):

Do you definitely want to convert the cached file?

Instead you could include the `fileExtension` argument when you call `.putFile`:

```
var file = await DefaultCacheManager().putFile(realPath + "/WhatCarCanYouGetForAGrand.mp4", bytes, fileExtension: 'mp4');
```

That way the cache won't change it to `.file` in the first place.